Execution failed for task ':charset_converter:compileDebugKotlin'
I get the error above when i try run my app on Android device.
But only, if open my Flutter project. When i open only Android module, i don't get this error, and app runs fine.
app/build.gradle seems like
    compileSdkVersion 34
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}

I use

Gradle 8.7.0
Kotlin 1.9.23
Android Studio LadyBug 2024.2.1
setted "Build, Execution, Deployment / Build tools / Gradle" Gradle JDK to "jbr-17" in Android Studio (btw i can set this only when i open only Android module, if i open Flutter project, this setting didn't show).
Tried set Java to 21, 1.8, 11, but nothing helped, only the

Execution failed for task ':charset_converter:compileDebugKotlin'.
Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (17) and 'compileDebugKotlin' (21).
Consider using JVM Toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain
Learn more about JVM-target validation: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation
error mesage.
No idea what to do.

added
kotlin.jvm.target.validation.mode=IGNORE

to gradle.propertys solved
